# Sending data between two programs on the same computer in TCL?

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I'm looking for a way for one program to send a string to another program (both in TCL). I've been looking into "threading", however I haven't been able to understand how it works and how to do what I want with it.

Comment: I would use a server-client type of architecture, using the [`socket`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/socket.htm) command

Comment: Is one a subprocess of the other? Tcl is actually really good at handling pipelines (by comparison with so many other languages). Otherwise, you're either going to want to use a platform-specific mechanism or a socket.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the `comm` package in `tcllib`. This package provides remote script execution between Tcl interpreters using sockets as the communications mechanism. Since both sides are in Tcl, this is an easy way to go.